# Is there a reason to use Link instead of NavLink in React Router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Since `NavLink` just have extra possible style than `Link` in React Router, can we always use `NavLink`? Is there a reason why we would use `Link` instead of `NavLink`?

Answer (score 0):

See the [documentation](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/NavLink.md)

Basically, NavLink and Link are exactly the same except NavLink adds the styling attributes when appropriate. It should be safe to always use NavLink. I prefer to only use NavLink for menu's but to each their own.